# Powershell Convert String With ENV Variable

Tags: powershell, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
$myVar = 'C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop'
Test-Path "$myVar"
```

The variable `$myVar` is needed with single quotes to display the actual variables used to the user.
How can I then actually process the variable later into the actual path to use?

Test-Path `$myVar` returns `False`, not seeing the users path `"C:\Users\User\Desktop"`

Comment: there is no need for the double quotes around your variable in the `Test-Path` call. it forces the object to be "stringified" [similar to calling `.ToString()`] ... and that item is already a string. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4):

Found it! As the single quotes could not be changed in the original variable `$myVar`, the following worked to expand its variable later:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($myVar)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This let's me store $variable in a JSON configuration file and expand it in the scripts I use.

Comment: your comment just saved my day! I was about to ask specifically about using strings stored in JSON files when I noticed this little gem.. :)

Comment: Happy to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
$myvar = "C:\Users\$($env:username)\Desktop"
Test-Path "$myvar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myVar = "C:\Users\"+$env:USERNAME+"\Desktop"
Test-Path $myVar
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.

Comment: This will not help, + cannot concatenate strings and variables.

Comment: + will help us concate the strings, here i also following the same. I have executed in my system and got expected output..