# How to convert the Start-Job -ArgumentList to proper values

Tags: powershell

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356208/is-there-a-way-in-powershell-to-get-the-default-value-of-a-script-parameter/64358608#64358608) we are able to read the default values of script parameters. Sometimes the parameters can contain an environment variable:

```bsh
# $script = c:\myScripts.ps1
Param (
    [String]$LogFolder = "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Log",
    [String[]]$ComputerName = @('PC1', $env:COMPUTERNAME)
)
```

When feeding this to the `-ArgumentList` of `Start-Job` it simply isn't converted to a value so the executed script fails:

```
VERBOSE: Parameter name 'LogFolder' value '\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Log'
VERBOSE: Parameter name 'ComputerName' value 'PC1', '$env:COMPUTERNAME'
```

Is there a way to have powershell convert this to the correct values? In this specific case it concerns a single `string` but it could just as well be an array of `string`.

**Desired result**

```
VERBOSE: Parameter name 'LogFolder' value '\\myComputerName\Log'
VERBOSE: Parameter name 'ComputerName' value 'PC1', 'myComputerName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480435/powershell-convert-string-with-env-variable) we found what we were looking for:

```bsh
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("Env:\COMPUTERNAME")
```